# Почему не работает расширение для браузера?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome-extension, extension, firefox-extension

Есть расширение `https://cloud.mail.ru/public/48Gt/47Xoqa6AY` Делали нам его на заказ. Но Мозилла завернула его, написав что jquery.min.js файл модифицирован. Проверил, внутри файла отсутствует вначале информация о лицензии. Начал сравнивать и проверять к какой версии jquery относится данный код. Консоль браузера показала, что это версия 3.2.1.min Зашел на сайт нашел такую версию вот она `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js`, заменил в расширении файл на оригинальный, расширение перестало работать. Воспользовался онлайн сервисами сравнения двух файлов. Сравнение показало, что файлы отличаются информацией о лицензии. В не оригинальной версии ее нет. решил проверить еще раз. Взял в оригинальной версии удалил информацию о лицензии, теперь файлы идентичны, сохранил (UTF-8). Расширение не работает. Уже голову сломал в чем причина. При использовании оригинального файла возникают вот такие ошибки, хотя версия та же и содержание файлов одинаковое.

1. Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
2. Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
3. Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
4. Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection.
   Receiving end does not exist.

Пожалуйста помогите решить задачу. Разработчик на связь не выходит. Спасибо

Comment: 4 пункт говорит что не может подключится. Возможно Вы из Украины и у Вас происходит блокировка какая то?

Comment: @AlexandrVyshnyvetskyi Россия

Comment: Ошибка номер 1. В каком файле ?

Comment: @AlexandrVyshnyvetskyi Вот в этом https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js

Comment: @AlexandrVyshnyvetskyi Вот на это жалуется /*! jQuery v3.2.1 | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/license */

Comment: @AlexandrVyshnyvetskyi Возникает, когда я не оригинальный jquery на оригинальный меняю

Comment: установил расширение себе, похоже что все работает. https://prnt.sc/pv08i7 как вы поняли что оно не работает?

Comment: @AlexandrVyshnyvetskyi Если вы с архива устанавливали, то в нем не оригинальный jquery и да он работает, а вот уже с оригинальным jquery https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2EbL/5e9mi3E7q и оно уже не работает.

Comment: если открыть файл с о котром вы говорите, то там иероглифы в прямом смысле этого слова - http://prntscr.com/pv0r1d.
1. Посмотрел исходники. Все файлы сохранены в кодировке UTF-8 with BOM - http://prntscr.com/pv0qlp
2.Файл code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js отличается и сохранен в формате просто UTF-8 из за этого и ломается кодировка.

Нужно пересохранить файл в формате UTF-8 with BOM и все заработает

Comment: @AlexandrVyshnyvetskyi Я скачивал переходя по ссылке https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js нажимал CNTR+S и заменял не оригинальный файл оригиналом. Если я изменю кодировку подозреваю Мозилла сново напишет что файл модифицирован

Comment: Все работает, я пересохранил в нужной кодировке.

Comment: @AlexandrVyshnyvetskyi А вы можете пересохраненный файл на облако залить?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WMr8tZhZCdHNjStAuVoILHKLek4NJLXu

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100878/discussion-between-arcadiy-and-alexandr-vyshnyvetskyi).

Comment: @AlexandrVyshnyvetskyi Странно, заработало, возникает вопрос, почему jquery размещает свои скрипты в неправильной кодировке. Оформите ответ, я приму его. Надеюсь Мозилла не завернет расширение. Спасибо

Comment: Скорее наоборот. UTF-8 with BOM у вас а не UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в несовместимости кодировки файла который вы загрузили с вашим расширением. Нужно пересохранить файл в кодировке UTF-8 with BOM

Comment: Спасибо, буду надеяться что примут.